# object has no attribute 'func_name'

Tags: python

При импорте гугловской *API* библиотеки `import gdata` выдается ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_name'.

Подскажите что, я не так делаю.

Comment: А Вы точно все установили? и версия питона подходящая? (вроде с 2.2 оно не работает, но нужно постараться найти его).

Comment: у меня 3.4.Ставлю библиотеки через PyCharm,который сообщил мне,что библиотека встала ровно

Comment: либо оно криво стало (не доверяю графическим утилитам), либо версия питона не подходит.

Либо просто нужно перезапустить ide/прописать пути в path.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из сообщения об ошибке можно сделать вывод, что библиотека `gdata` не поддерживает Python 3. В Python 3 `func_*` атрибуты [были переименованы](http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#funcattrs). В частности `func_name` переименован в `__name__`.

Придется использовать Python 2.x или пытаться портировать библиотеку.